# Rails Troubles with my relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, relation, belongs-to, has-one

I want to have a model `Game` with have two users: `user1` and `user2`

This is my two models with their migrations:

game.rb:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord

has_secure_token

# @!group RELATIONS
has_many :turns, dependent: :destroy
has_many :play_cards, dependent: :destroy
has_one :user1, class_name: 'User', dependent: :destroy
has_one :user2, class_name: 'User', dependent: :destroy
# @!endgroup

# @!group VALIDATORS
validates :user1_id, presence: true, blank: false, nill: false
validates :user2_id, presence: true, blank: false, nill: false
validates :finish_at, presence: true, blank: false, nill: false
validates :token, presence: true, blank: false, nill: false, length: { is: 24 }
# @!endgroup

end
```

Migration:

```
def change
create_table :games do |t|
  t.references :user1, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
  t.references :user2, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
  t.string :token, length: { is: 24 }, null: false
  t.datetime :finish_at, null: false

  t.timestamps
end
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

has_secure_token :token

# @!group RELATIONS
has_many :decks, dependent: :destroy
has_one :chosen_deck, class_name: 'Deck', dependent: :destroy
has_many :turns, dependent: :destroy
# @!endgroup

# @!group VALIDATORS
validates :hp, presence: true, blank: false, nill: false, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
validates :armor, presence: true, blank: false, nill: false, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
validates :token, presence: true, blank: false, nill: false, length: { is: 24 }, on: :save
validates :name, presence: true, blank: false, nill: false, length: { minimum: 4 }
# @!endgroup

end
```

Migration:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.references :chosen_deck, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :decks }
  t.string :name, null: false
  t.integer :hp, null: false, default: 20
  t.integer :armor, null: false, default: 0
  t.string :token, length: { is: 24 }, null: false

  t.timestamps
end
```

The trouble append when I try to save game with that:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `game_id`
```

I put a screenshot here: [error screen](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/19/1/1525712770-screen-shot-2018-05-07-at-19-05-10.png)

Have a nice day,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `game_id`

The problem is in exactly what the error says. `User` model lacks `game_id` attribute, which is required by convention for connecting a user and a game (if you want another column for that, it should be specified explicitly as a foreign_key)

Just create a `game_id` column for `users` and specify (not necessary) `belongs_to :game` in `User` model, since user `belongs_to` a game.

Otherwise, since you have `user1_id` and `user2_id`, you need to change `has_one` to `belongs_to`. Then it will update these `belongs_to` columns instead of looking for `game_id` in the `has_one` associations.

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  # @!group RELATIONS
  has_many :turns, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :play_cards, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user1, class_name: 'User', dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user2, class_name: 'User', dependent: :destroy
  # @!endgroup
end
```

Comment: Usually the foreign_key is on the child. He seems to have added the foreign_key on the parent. The game migration should not make references to users.

Comment: I don't understand why I need a game_id on user because I already have a user1_id and user2_id on game. Can you explain ?

Comment: be careful: t.references creates a foreign key. Though Game should have no reference to the users because Game is a parent of User. Instead User should have a reference to Game. You migrated the foreign keys on the wrong model (If i am not mistaken)

Comment: @AlexisCHEVREUX I updated the answer. When you have `has_one` association, Rails tries to store a "connection" value into the `has_one` record, i. e. looks for `game_id` in the `user1` and `user2`

Comment: i agree with this answer. With the references you created in the games table, `Game` belongs to user1 and user2, and `User` has many games.  Your code in console should work this way.